# Application crashes/closes in between Test Execution

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I'm getting an issue that my application crashes or closes (as it minimizes or goes in background, and when maximizing or launching it again it opens fresh from the start screen, which suggest the application is getting closed or crashed) in between the test execution. I'm executing these testcases using data-driven framework. So it goes upto row number 7 or 8 and then the application closes automatically.
Below is the command from Appium log which i think is showing the cause. Please help!!!

> Command 260: [debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-08-04 05:47:27 +0000
>   Debug: Got new command 260 from instruments:
>   au.getElement('60').setValueByType('Moonlight Storytime: Insect
>   Minstrels')
>
> [debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-08-04 05:47:27 +0000 Debug:
>   evaluating au.getElement('60').setValueByType('Moonlight Storytime:
>   Insect Minstrels')
>
> [debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-08-04 05:47:27 +0000 Debug:
>   target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("Moonlight Storytime:
>   Insect Minstrels")
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:28 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:28 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   mediaserverd[435] : '' (pid = 515) setting DiscoveryMode =
>   DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:28 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Communications error:  { length
>   = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] }> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:28 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   SpringBoard[54] : Communications error:  { length
>   = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] }>
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:28 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:28 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   com.apple.CDScheduler[23] : SysAdmChk: Throttling activity execution.
>   memFlags:0x1 thermalLevel:0x0
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   accountsd[539] : [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all
>   accounts
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   accountsd[539] : [Warning] Bad response (null) from daemon for setup
>   info
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   accountsd[539] : [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all
>   enabled accounts
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   accountsd[539] : [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all
>   dependent devices
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:29 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:30 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:30 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:30 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:31 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:31 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:31 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:31 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:31 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   CuriousWorld[528] : Start backspacing timer
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   UserEventAgent[23] : jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   mediaserverd[435] : '' (pid = 427) setting DiscoveryMode =
>   DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None [iOSLog]
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad CuriousWorld[528] :
>   LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service
>   com.apple.lsd.advertisingidentifiers [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4
>   11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad CuriousWorld[528] : LaunchServices:
>   disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb [iOSLog]
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad apsd[441] :
>   LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service
>   com.apple.lsd.mapdb
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   sharingd[446] : 11:17:32.722 : SDConnectionManager:: XPC connection
>   invalidated [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   mediaserverd[435] : '' (pid = 427) setting DiscoveryMode =
>   DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None [iOSLog]
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad mediaserverd[435] :
>   LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service
>   com.apple.lsd.mapdb [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32
>   v-mirzabaigs-iPad SpringBoard[54] : LaunchServices: disconnect event
>   received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug
>   4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad CommCenter[75] : Connection interrupted!
>   [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   locationd[438] : LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service
>   com.apple.lsd.mapdb [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32
>   v-mirzabaigs-iPad ScriptAgent[529] : LaunchServices: disconnect event
>   received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug
>   4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad filecoordinationd[484] : LaunchServices:
>   disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb [iOSLog]
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   containermanagerd[551] : 0x19fbfe000 -[MCMGlobalConfiguration init]:
>   Current mobile user ID is 501
>
> [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 4 11:17:32 v-mirzabaigs-iPad
>   assertiond[63] : LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service
>   com.apple.lsd.mapdb

It is producing JetSam log which is below:

> {"timestamp":"2016-08-05 15:10:28.28
>   +0530","bug_type":"298","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.3.2 (13F69)"} {"timestamp":"2016-08-05 15:10:28.28
>   +0530","bug_type":"298","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.3.2 (13F69)"} { "crashReporterKey" : "57ab7d3a1cf27c21f4875f0ea15a43c58f07c5ad",
>   "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Mon Apr 18 16:44:06 PDT
>   2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~4/RELEASE_ARM64_S5L8960X", "product" :
>   "iPad4,1", "incident" : "C2C1FC70-DD6F-47BC-9708-81238C98F247", "date"
>   : "2016-08-05 15:10:28.28 +0530", "build" : "iPhone OS 9.3.2 (13F69)",
>   "timeDelta" : 2378, "memoryStatus" : { "compressorSize" : 89247,
>   "pageSize" : 4096, "compressions" : 5013347, "memoryPages" : {
>   "active" : 55510, "throttled" : 0, "fileBacked" : 36530, "wired" :
>   74426, "anonymous" : 47029, "purgeable" : 0, "inactive" : 25229,
>   "free" : 4374, "speculative" : 2820 }, "uncompressed" : 244802,
>   "decompressions" : 1047863 }, "largestProcess" : "CuriousWorld",
>   "processes" : [ { "rpages" : 1414, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ],
>   "name" : "DTServiceHub", "pid" : 1135, "reason" : "vm-thrashing",
>   "fds" : 50, "uuid" : "966b08b9-a587-31b2-b276-a0512ed252a5",
>   "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" : 3.972588, "lifetimeMax" : 2565 }, {
>   "rpages" : 171, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" :
>   "diagnosticd", "pid" : 1187, "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50,
>   "uuid" : "b54e689e-4fde-320c-9146-44f5d2e706e0", "purgeable" : 0,
>   "cpuTime" : 0.02126, "lifetimeMax" : 322 }, { "rpages" : 112, "states"
>   : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "notification_pro", "pid" : 1175,
>   "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "8f09b04e-3bf7-3fbe-89dc-39164ca308f7", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.01988, "lifetimeMax" : 251 }, { "rpages" : 145, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "pasteboardd", "pid" : 1185, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "8bd1a48f-c0f6-3209-9b08-c7bb4aa734ff", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.020079, "lifetimeMax" : 335 }, { "rpages" : 120, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "rtcreportingd", "pid" : 1176, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "5114fa84-c23b-33b2-b6d6-9eb3f61badc5", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.018726, "lifetimeMax" : 271 }, { "rpages" : 159, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "MobileGestaltHel", "pid" : 1184,
>   "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "1ff88a01-02c8-34a7-b4fd-d70aa66e5ddc", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.023518, "lifetimeMax" : 365 }, { "rpages" : 303, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "containermanager", "pid" : 1182,
>   "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "4f8a1cab-bb73-3467-b2de-cdc9ef801eb9", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.091644, "lifetimeMax" : 594 }, { "rpages" : 177, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "useractivityd", "pid" : 1179, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "46467a6a-705d-3bdb-b4ad-72b709bcd89b", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.029211, "lifetimeMax" : 452 }, { "rpages" : 253, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "WirelessRadioMan", "pid" : 1173, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "66be92d3-16fc-3ad4-a2e9-010fa9dff1df", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.079181, "lifetimeMax" : 598 }, { "rpages" : 104, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "routined", "pid" : 1174, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "e6efb65b-2d62-3b83-8958-ed1f1823edae", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.021927, "lifetimeMax" : 448 }, { "rpages" : 68, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "nsurlsessiond", "pid" : 1172, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "09b9b853-7414-347c-87bf-8c930857fb67", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.015996, "lifetimeMax" : 213 }, { "rpages" : 658, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "duetexpertd", "pid" : 1171, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "ca76e2a6-1650-363c-8cce-1ed7ab01fc61", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.267506, "lifetimeMax" : 1397 }, { "rpages" : 46, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "bird", "pid" : 1189, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "9f82cc25-f51f-3d0d-aa55-a56c72734ff7", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.012455, "lifetimeMax" : 194 }, { "rpages" : 221, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "lsd", "pid" : 1180, "reason" : "vm-thrashing",
>   "fds" : 50, "uuid" : "e4c9a336-8836-3dfb-aad9-4b54adc0d7a7",
>   "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" : 0.070128, "lifetimeMax" : 496 }, {
>   "rpages" : 586, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "kbd", "pid" : 1183,
>   "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "4b832c37-2957-3730-9463-359bcf1c4a99", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.273692, "lifetimeMax" : 1179 }, { "rpages" : 1430, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "coreduetd", "pid" : 1178, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "5adcb45d-65c8-3ccf-be77-ae07ad783213", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.931295, "lifetimeMax" : 2461 }, { "rpages" : 191, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "tccd", "pid" : 1190, "reason" : "vm-thrashing",
>   "fds" : 50, "uuid" : "36f22d9c-5204-37fd-80fd-0f8d8117dcd7",
>   "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" : 0.041341, "lifetimeMax" : 450 }, {
>   "rpages" : 48855, "states" : [ "frontmost", "resume" ], "name" :
>   "CuriousWorld", "pid" : 1136, "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50,
>   "uuid" : "d7de6f56-c1da-39d2-a36d-da5472b60a6e", "purgeable" : 3,
>   "pageSpike" : 11, "cpuTime" : 102.724544, "lifetimeMax" : 32850 }, {
>   "rpages" : 717, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "ptpd", "pid" :
>   1039, "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "5f9178b6-3a3e-311d-97be-39bf0821d287", "purgeable" : 48, "cpuTime" :
>   1.092776, "lifetimeMax" : 1064 }, { "rpages" : 376, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "BTServer", "pid" : 1040, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "fd1b9a4d-82a3-3c70-b96a-8e49fa7f1fee", "purgeable" : 10, "cpuTime" :
>   0.202729, "lifetimeMax" : 1010 }, { "rpages" : 27074, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "mediaserverd", "pid" : 1042, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "c8b6abd8-9ed8-3152-b401-8696d614158c", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   67.231298, "lifetimeMax" : 20063 }, { "rpages" : 303, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "iaptransportd", "pid" : 1047, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "1b32d104-0592-387d-87b4-e9b6808c7de2", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.191484, "lifetimeMax" : 664 }, { "rpages" : 644, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "sharingd", "pid" : 1050, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "a464b60f-1b3d-3024-8cb7-b897481ed16c", "purgeable" : 11, "cpuTime" :
>   0.274182, "lifetimeMax" : 1192 }, { "rpages" : 1392, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "locationd", "pid" : 1043, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "93d2212d-aca6-31d0-a0bb-72e89d39c046", "purgeable" : 71, "cpuTime" :
>   3.194177, "lifetimeMax" : 3272 }, { "rpages" : 436, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "imagent", "pid" : 1044, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "ddde7a5b-d726-30f6-b36c-11761ed37881", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.34401, "lifetimeMax" : 907 }, { "rpages" : 282, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "mDNSResponder", "pid" : 1045, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "131b8966-d207-3602-8f77-302073be50ac", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   1.736284, "lifetimeMax" : 577 }, { "rpages" : 535, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "wifid", "pid" : 1041, "reason" : "vm-thrashing",
>   "fds" : 50, "uuid" : "c6a5761d-4205-3fda-8fc9-5288e229f8c2",
>   "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" : 1.280231, "lifetimeMax" : 1182 }, {
>   "rpages" : 722, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "identityservices",
>   "pid" : 1046, "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "d75b47ba-41d9-36f7-984f-126b4f1bb918", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.772517, "lifetimeMax" : 1493 }, { "rpages" : 206, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "syslogd", "pid" : 1048, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "497057fe-81b7-3ae4-9e9f-9b0a22d70e0a", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   5.024219, "lifetimeMax" : 328 }, { "rpages" : 708, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "apsd", "pid" : 1052, "reason" : "vm-thrashing",
>   "fds" : 50, "uuid" : "6dd76fda-e07f-3efc-9dc9-1451b3eb5269",
>   "purgeable" : 5, "cpuTime" : 0.9857860000000001, "lifetimeMax" : 1458
>   }, { "rpages" : 387, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "cfprefsd",
>   "pid" : 1059, "reason" : "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "b91e1dd6-2a32-3d4d-b740-353bd13985d2", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   2.23125, "lifetimeMax" : 486 }, { "rpages" : 571, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "symptomsd", "pid" : 1053, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "fc0575dc-0b33-343f-8eda-965bec629017", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   1.024675, "lifetimeMax" : 926 }, { "rpages" : 224, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "powerd", "pid" : 1049, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "efbaa2e4-cac3-358d-a8ff-239e57bae194", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.442325, "lifetimeMax" : 442 }, { "rpages" : 402, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "networkd", "pid" : 1051, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "fa8f0a3b-690c-3b2a-9517-0929651cca8e", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.943627, "lifetimeMax" : 730 }, { "rpages" : 123, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "syslog_relay", "pid" : 1055, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "6f5109ae-6849-3e58-a5b4-a0006af66735", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.1217, "lifetimeMax" : 271 }, { "rpages" : 623, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "securityd", "pid" : 1057, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "f636824f-69a2-344a-a074-15095496c063", "purgeable" : 77, "cpuTime" :
>   8.540886, "lifetimeMax" : 1153 }, { "rpages" : 286, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "awdd", "pid" : 1188, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "2cff7a5c-6494-36c7-b1ac-9ca0764142f9", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.087857, "lifetimeMax" : 630 }, { "rpages" : 284, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "mobileassetd", "pid" : 1186, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "b9cf4a1a-bfd2-3e79-be9a-8ff07c12c8f1", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.22317, "lifetimeMax" : 612 }, { "rpages" : 450, "states" : [ "daemon", "idle" ], "name" : "assetsd", "pid" : 1181, "reason" :
>   "vm-thrashing", "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "ca9217f6-3337-3a78-9369-c0ef7c6c9010", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.074186, "lifetimeMax" : 841 }, { "rpages" : 8848, "states" : [
>
> ], "name" : "SpringBoard", "pid" : 54, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "a45b12c0-6d08-3911-9ba0-cafddee58ec1", "purgeable" : 44, "cpuTime" :
>   103.664728, "lifetimeMax" : 46274 }, { "rpages" : 21536, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "backboardd", "pid" : 56, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "9404d3cd-4774-340f-a012-da95c8357c93", "purgeable" : 8, "cpuTime" :
>   944.967433, "lifetimeMax" : 3139 }, { "rpages" : 1026, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "UserEventAgent", "pid" : 23, "fds" : 200, "uuid"
>   : "a16c7815-0c22-3f43-ab9e-b06ca2c2ce02", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   39.477229, "lifetimeMax" : 1801 }, { "rpages" : 345, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "fseventsd", "pid" : 26, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "7cb6fca8-3198-3c39-ba5c-44e5dbc18183", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   7.261698, "lifetimeMax" : 575 }, { "rpages" : 452, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "configd", "pid" : 35, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "a3172ef8-50bc-39c5-9830-472bce049a04", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   2.873326, "lifetimeMax" : 907 }, { "rpages" : 210, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "fairplayd.A2", "pid" : 74, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "fbcb4bac-4b0a-3ef2-b957-1dd34dbe10f5", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.438476, "lifetimeMax" : 1078 }, { "rpages" : 193, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "wirelessproxd", "pid" : 55, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "3933db0e-ac7f-32ae-85b1-fb3d6ee1e133", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.192515, "lifetimeMax" : 402 }, { "rpages" : 269, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "assertiond", "pid" : 63, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "0b862a7d-6e8b-3778-ad17-c7694ecd5bcd", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   9.339428, "lifetimeMax" : 524 }, { "rpages" : 177, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "distnoted", "pid" : 80, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "0076ce76-b591-32b0-933b-c8c52d75ff0e", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.6088980000000001, "lifetimeMax" : 307 }, { "rpages" : 1380, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "aggregated", "pid" : 70, "fds" : 50, "uuid"
>   : "abe65f2a-0029-3467-ae1b-a7bf30fad3d6", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   41.05218, "lifetimeMax" : 1883 }, { "rpages" : 5078, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "ScriptAgent", "pid" : 1138, "fds" : 25, "uuid" :
>   "4c3ddc20-c033-3a4c-ac06-d089b9449eca", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   25.006006, "lifetimeMax" : 9343 }, { "rpages" : 318, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "accountsd", "pid" : 1191, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "85e94190-32e7-3ec5-acf6-a264fde48756", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.066164, "lifetimeMax" : 579 }, { "rpages" : 987, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "CommCenter", "pid" : 75, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "6530e934-66dd-3528-accf-e0541c0c7a11", "purgeable" : 10, "cpuTime" :
>   8.220686000000001, "lifetimeMax" : 3249 }, { "rpages" : 362, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "notifyd", "pid" : 77, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "e4005789-9708-3645-bdd2-3f32e5567a4c", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   15.86676, "lifetimeMax" : 466 }, { "rpages" : 249, "states" : [ "daemon" ], "name" : "ReportCrash", "pid" : 1177, "fds" : 50, "uuid" :
>   "2e37b1e4-ed2c-3995-b714-51da16cd1764", "purgeable" : 0, "cpuTime" :
>   0.062754, "lifetimeMax" : 534 } ] }

Please help!!!

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? Do you see crash reports on your iPad? Actually I am having the same issue. it suddenly goes into the background and when you bring it to the foreground the app is back on the start screen. All I see in the log is : disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb so I think this is a similar issue

Comment: I have noticed that this only occurs on devices with iOS 9.3.2 or higher. On all my devices with iOS 9.3.1 the app just works. After upgrading on of my devices to the latest iOS version (9.3.5) the app suddenly starts crashing.